# Text strike-through on check box selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I can't get it to work, I have a table that loops through a collection with a checkbox on each row and I want to strike-through the text of the description when the check box is selected?????. Thanks for the help!!

Table

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr><th>Task Description</th><th>Completed</th>
    @if (Model.ListOfTasks.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Tasks</td></tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var task in Model.ListOfTasks)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TaskID)                
                <td><span>@task.Description</span></td>
                <td>

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Complete", "Task", new { id = task.TaskID }))
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                    }

                </td>                
                <td>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Task", new { id = task.TaskID }))
                    {
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit">Remove</button>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>

<a href="#" onclick="ShowTaskPopup()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="popupTaskForm" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">Add New Task</div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Task", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <form class="well">
            <fieldset>
                <table class="table-condensed">                    
                    <tr class="strikeout">
                        <td><label>Task Name</label></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TaskName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                        <td><label>Description</label></td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              </fieldset>
        </form>           
     }
    </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
  $('#checkbox').change(function () {

            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("text-decoration","line-through");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html - use a class name instead

Comment: I'd also suggest you add/remove a class instead of using `css()` to add the styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor will add `<form>` tags around your checkbox, so you're applying the css to the `<td>` that contains the checkbox, not the parent row as you might think with parent().parent();

Try using the closest selector to traverse up the dom tree and find the parent row:

```
$(this).closest("tr").css("text-decoration","line-through");
```

Comment: ...also you should be using class names not IDs as noted by Mihai T below

Comment: Please accept answer if this helped you out.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`I want to strike-through the text of the when the check box is selected?????`
Of the ? i guess you mean the `description` . I made a simple example of your code so you can see that it works.

The problem is with the `HTML` . Because you are setting same id to the checkboxes, jq only works for one of them. Duplicate iD's cause this kind of problems. I replaced id's with classes . See below

( try to change, in jQuery, to `#` and you will see that it will no longer work for both checkboxes )

```js
 $('.checkbox').change(function() {

   if (this.checked) {
     $(this).parent().parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
   } else {
     $(this).parent().parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Strike me through</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Strike me through</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you. But in both you have to go with `class` not `ID` or you can use`[type="checkbox"]` but in opinion class is better for targeting elements, These are the appropriate 2 solutions in my mind, ty

***1#***

```js
 $('.checkbox').change(function() {

   if (this.checked) {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
   } else {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').css("text-decoration", "none");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>@task.Description</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>@task.Description</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***2#***

```js
 $('.checkbox').change(function() {

   if (this.checked) {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('td>span').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
   } else {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('td>span').css("text-decoration", "none");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>@task.Description</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>@task.Description</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code to help you out:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().parent().css({
      'text-decoration': 'line-through',
      'color': 'red'
    })
  } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().css({
      'text-decoration': 'none',
      'color': '#000'
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>some text</td>
  <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
</tr>
```